# How to calculate $e^{-0.4}, ~e^{-1.67}, ~e^{-5}, ~e^{0.6},~e^{1.23}, ~\text{and} ~e^{7}$ by hand

Tags: exponential-function

How can we calculate $e^{-0.4}, ~e^{-1.67}, ~e^{-5}, ~e^{0.6},~e^{1.23}, ~\text{and} ~e^{7}$ by hand (without using a calculator)?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the Taylor series of $e^x$? Approximate value of base ten log of $e$? Something else that might be useful here? Also: pleading urgency is a turn-off to many regulars here, so is unlikely to help your cause.

Comment: @PRITAM DAS: WHY DO YOU SHOUT AT US?

Comment: @PRITAMDAS: Welcome to MSE! Whay are you yelling with the capital letters? People find it rude to read questions stating give me answers as-soon-as-possible. Also, it help to show or provide ideas of what you have tried. Regards

Comment: Use a slide rule, or log book.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on what you know and how accurate you want to be.  For small values of $x$ you can use the Taylor series $e^x \approx 1+x+\frac {x^2}2$.  Any more terms than that is too hard.  This will work pretty well for $-0.4, 0.6$  The error for $0.6$ is about $0.036$ on $1.78$ or $2\%$, which I would call very good.  Then for $1.23$ you can square $1.78$ and multiply by $1.03$.  For $-0.4$ I get $0.68$ from the Taylor series.

For $7$, maybe you know that $\log 10 \approx 2.30$, which gives us that $e^{6.9} \approx 1000$ and $e^7\approx 1.1\cdot 1000 =1100$.  The correct value is about $1096.63$

For $-5$ I would say $e^{-4.6} \approx 0.01$, and so $e^{-5}=e^{-4.6}e^{-.4}\approx 0.0068$

For $1.23$ I would probably use $e^{1.23}=\sqrt{e^{2.3}}e^{0.08}\approx 1.08\sqrt{10}\approx 1.08 \cdot 3.162$

For $-1.67$ (if I had already done the above) I would probably invert the $1.23$ result and multiply by $e^{-0.4}\approx 0.68$.  If not, I would probably use $\log 2 \approx 0.69$ anddo $e^{-1.67}=e^{-1.38}e^{-.35}e^{0.04}\approx 0.25\cdot 0.707\cdot 1.04$

I played fair, though I checked the numbers with a calculator, I did these by hand.

Answer (score 2):

As for "how we can calculate $e^x$ for given values of $x$:"

See the Wikipedia entry: [**Taylor Series**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansion#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), for common functions, first listing the expansion of $e^x$:

$$e^{x} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots\quad\text{ for all } x\!$$

- It the section immediately following that, there is an outline for [**Calculation of Taylor Series**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansion#Calculation_of_Taylor_series), using specific examples.

---

As to actually calculating the specific values you list: I'll leave that work to you. 
Knowing this, you have all the tools you need linked/listed above. And you can minimize your work by noting $$\;e^{x+y} = e^xe^y\;\text{ and}\;\;e^{x-y} = \dfrac{e^x}{e^y},\;$$ so once compute, e.g., $\;e^{0.6},\;$ then you can easily compute $\;e^{-0.4} = e^{0.6 - 1} = \dfrac{e^{0.6}}{e}$.

Comment: Thnx a lot for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, Pritam!